# React Google Maps get bounds of Polyline

Tags: react-typescript, google-polyline, react-google-maps, strava

I have been playing around with the Strava developer API a bit and been building a basic React app to fetch soem Starva activites and display it in a list.  Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/loanburger/strava-react-app).

I have a map that renders the activity route in this component.

```
const StravaMap = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(({ zoom, activity }: StravaMapProps) => {
    const center = {
      lat: activity.start_latitude,
      lng: activity.start_longitude,
    };

    const path = activity.map.summary_polyline
      ? createPath(polyline.decode(activity.map.summary_polyline))
      : [];

    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={zoom}
        defaultCenter={center}
        defaultOptions={mapOptions}
      >
        <Marker position={center} />
        {path.length > 0 && (
          <Polyline options={polyLineOptions} path={path} visible />
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }),
);
```

Source file [here](https://github.com/loanburger/strava-react-app/blob/main/project/src/components/Strava/StravaMap.tsx).

The polygon renders fine, but I am now trying to figure out how I can zoom the map to fit th epolyline into bounds.

I may be mising soemthing but I dont have a clear idea how to get hold of the polyline instance to get bounds or the map to set bounds.

I know how to buffer the poluyline based on the path but once I have done thay and have the bounds, how can I set the bound using this **React Google Maps** library?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more digging and research I have found a workable solution I'll share for the benefit of others:

I found this post on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/305#issuecomment-352381608)

Using that I created a helper function to create the `google.maps.LatLngBounds`

```
export const createBounds = (path: IPoint[]): google.maps.LatLngBounds => {
  const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  path.map((p: IPoint) => bounds.extend(p));
  return bounds;
};
```

In my StravaMap component I then pass the path we had to this function and get the bounds like this:

```
const bounds = createBounds(path);
```

I can then pass that to the GoogleMap component using the ref like:

```
  ref={(map) => map && map.fitBounds(bounds)}
```

And that successfully sets the map bound when the activity is loaded.